# Reference a specific value within a dplyr group by case

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data similar to below, representing interactions between entities.

```
> library(tidyverse)
> set.seed(20)
> dta <- data_frame(group=c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
           flag=c(1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1),
           name=c('a','b','a','c','d','b','c','c'),
           amount=rnorm(8,20))
# A tibble: 8 x 4
  group  flag name  amount
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
1     1     1  a      21.2
2     1     0  b      19.4
3     2     1  a      21.8
4     2     1  c      18.7
5     2     0  d      19.6
6     3     0  b      20.6
7     3     1  c      17.1
8     3     1  c      19.1
```

There can be one-to-one relationships, one entity sending to many others, or many entities receiving from one. The group column denotes an interaction, and flag denotes sending/receiving (does not matter which is occurring).

For a network analysis, I need to `group_by` the group column, and then create a column called "to" that contains the value of "name" from the row in the group where flag is the only 1 or 0 in its group. In the case of a one-to-one interaction, I assign the name from the row with `flag == 1`.

I want something like this:

```
dta %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(to = case_when(sum(.$flag) == 1 ~ .$name[.$flag == 1],
                        sum(.$flag == 0) == 1 ~ .$name[.$flag == 0],
                        TRUE ~ .$name[.$flag == 1]))

  group  flag name  amount  to
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <chr>
1     1     1  a      21.2  a
2     1     0  b      19.4  a
3     2     1  a      21.8  d
4     2     1  c      18.7  d
5     2     0  d      19.6  d
6     3     0  b      20.6  b
7     3     1  c      17.1  b
8     3     1  c      19.1  b
```

Using `mutate`, the `.$` refers to the entire `tbl` instead of the group. I'm sure this can be done with `do`, but I'm not very familiar with its uses, and it gives me an undesired structure when I replace the mutate call above with it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create a frequency column to do this

```
library(dplyr)
dta %>% 
   group_by(group, flag) %>% 
   mutate(n = n()) %>%
   group_by(group) %>%
   mutate(to = name[which(n ==1)[1]]) %>% 
   select(-n)
# A tibble: 8 x 5
# Groups:   group [3]
#  group  flag name  amount to   
#  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <chr>
#1     1     1 a       21.2 a    
#2     1     0 b       19.4 a    
#3     2     1 a       21.8 d    
#4     2     1 c       18.7 d    
#5     2     0 d       19.6 d    
#6     3     0 b       20.6 b    
#7     3     1 c       17.1 b    
#8     3     1 c       19.1 b
```

---

Or instead of grouping by 'group' and 'flag', apply the `table` to get the frequency of 'flag' and extract the `name` that corresponds to frequency of 1

```
dta %>% 
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate(to = name[which(table(factor(flag, 
             levels = 0:1))[as.character(flag)] == 1)])
```